# jQuery Deferreds - Calling an array of Deferreds in succession

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise, jquery-deferred

So I've got an array of Deferred objects `dataCalls`.

At the moment I'm using the following to fire them all, and call a callback once all Deferreds have resolved:

```
$.when.apply(null, dataCalls)
   .always(callback);
```

It works fine. Now the problem is each Deferred in `dataCalls` fires off at the same time. how can I get them to fire in succession - I'm thinking about `Deferred.then`, and somehow `apply()` the array to `then()` but that assumes you have a Deferred to start off with, which I don't.

I'm thinking perhaps of looping through the array, and passing each Deferred object into the previous Deferred's `then()` method. Then follow with:

```
$.when(dataCalls[0])
   .always(callback);
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

It's been a long day, let me clean up this question so it can be of use to someone else hopefully.

As opposed so what I first wrote, I actually have an array of `Deferred.promise()` objects, `dataCalls`.

This is then passed into:

```
$.when.apply(null, dataCalls)
   .always(callback);
```

so that the callback is invoked when all of the promises are resolved.

Since the Deferred objects that return each promise have already been invoked, and (in other code not shown) that process is very fast, each Deferred runs concurrently.

To get the Deferreds firing in succession, I need to instead create an array with each object in the array being a function that returns the said promise.

I can then loop over the array, execute the function that returns the promise, then pass the next object in the array into the .then() method of the promise, which will cause the function to be invoked when the promise is resolved.

The last promise can then be passed back into `$.when(promise).always(callback);`.

Comment: first, you'll have to stop creating the dataCalls array. The calls are sent while you generate the array of promise objects. show us that code.

Comment: @KevinB Okay a bit of a stupid moment there, each object in my array is actually a function that returns a Deferred.promise(). That array is then passed currently to $.when.apply(null, array);

Comment: No, each object is the promise object returned by each function, otherwise $.when would have been resolving instantly rather than waiting for the requests to complete. $.when doesn't execute functions.

Comment: @KevinB Yes you're right, sorry, each object in the array is a promise. I think it might be time to go home lol.

Comment: I'll put together a sample, assuming you have an array of ajax option objects.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks, the Deferred is resolved on an ajax call success. The array is as you said before an array of Deferred.promise()s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over them, passing each into .then

```
var reqArr = [{url: "somepage.php"},{url: "somepage1.php"},{url: "somepage2.php"}];

var req = $.ajax(reqArr.shift());
$.each(reqArr,function(i,obj){
    req.then(function(){
        return $.ajax(obj);
    });
});

req.done(function(){
    //They are all done!
});
```

Comment: I see what you've done but I've encapsulated this logic within the Deferred. I only have the promise. But the Deferred executes when called immediately and the $.when just waits for the promise to be resolved I believe, so I think I need to refactor my code quite a bit.

Comment: If you have the promise, then the request has already been sent. so, yes, you'll have to refactor it a bit.

Comment: I've had a quick read and I think instead of building the array I can just pass one promise into the then() of the previous promise as I loop over them. Then I can pass the last promise into $.when as it is currently. - make that "pass the function that provides the promise"

Comment: wait... do you really care about what order they finish? would it be enough to just iterate over the results in the correct order?

Comment: At the moment, them being called concurrently causes a race condition on the server. So as long as they are called one after the other it doesn't matter what order.

Comment: In that case you just need to make sure you are generating the promise objects one at a time, after the previous has resolved. passing the promise objects one at a time won't accomplish anything.

Comment: Yup just got that, thanks Kevin. I'll mark your answer since you've got my head thinking straight ;)